# Java How to get timer value when it

Tags: java, swing, timer

I made a simple timer by using the Timer class and i want to get the value of the timer when it is stopped. That's my code:

```
private Timer timer;

public Main() {
timer = new Timer(1000, new Listener());
timer.start();

......

timer.stop();
}
```

How can i get the time of the timer?

Like:

```
double time = timer.stop();
```

Thanks.

Comment: Timers don't have a value. Are you looking for a way to measure the elapsed time?

Comment: I was going to say the exact same thing -- Swing Timer's don't have "*values*". You can use it to change the state of a field in the class, and likely that's what you want to do. Consider creating and posting your [mcve] so we can have small code that we can run and test.

Comment: Timer's do have state however such as `isRunning()`, but I doubt that this is what you're looking for.

Comment: But they don't have a `stop` method...

Comment: @AndyTurner: ??? According to my [Java 8 API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html), a Swing Timer **does** have a `stop()` method. Please clarify your statement above. It returns a boolean however, not an int.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels huh. So there is. <cleans glasses>